# Concatenate all fields of a MySQL record into a string without knowing the field names (with SQL query)

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate all fields of a record into a single comma separated string in MySQL without listing the field names? (For tables where I don't know what the fields names may all be) for example:

```sql
SET @colnames := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('\`',COLUMN_NAME), '\`') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = "mytable" and table_schema='mydb');
set @valuess := concat_ws('\',\'',@colnames);
```

or set `@valuess := concat_ws(',',select * from mydb.mytable);`

Sorry if there is an obvious answer. I searched but could not find one.

Comment: You could use data from information_schema to dynamically construct a query that references the fields explicitly; but not in one query there isn't. Why would you need to this in a sql query? It sounds like something much more appropriate for the client code to handle.

Comment: I use this in a trigger that records changes made to a table, the table I am tracking has had its schema changed a few times and probably will in the future, fields added deleted, renamed several times which is creating issues for my application. I am hoping to make everything more generic to avoid trouble in the future. I have also thought about dropping the triggers and using php to update the tracker table. But I was hoping for a quick fix, and was just curious why its not a straight forward query which evaluates the @colnames within the concat_ws() function.

Comment: In my opinion, triggers should really be treated as part of the table definition to avoid such problems.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using JSON or XML instead of concatenation but If your table's definition is changing so frequently I suggest you need to re-think your data model.